# tabularx inside `small` produces underfull hbox

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx, fontsize, badness

I have a table implemented with tabularx and I want all the text inside my table to be "small".

Putting the tabularx inside a `small` environment seems to work just fine, except it produces a warning `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph`. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

{\small
\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|}
  Hot & Dog \\
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

The warning seems unwarranted (is it really?) and I could just ignore it, except it's part of a much bigger Latex project for which I've succeeded in eliminating all warnings and bad boxes so far. Is there a way I can either fix this or suppress this specific warning (but I wouldn't want to suppress any other potential bad boxes).

Comment: You might change `\end{tabularx}` to `\end{tabularx}%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unrelated to `tabularx` it is the space you added after the table ends up on a line on its own, use

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

{\small
\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|}
  Hot & Dog \\
\end{tabularx}

}

\end{document}
```

TeX removes one space (glue item) at the end of a paragraph but if you do

```
...
zzz
}

new para
```

then the paragraph ending `zzz` (or `tabularx` in your case)` has two space tokens at the end one is removed leaving one, and as your table was full width the remaining space token is forced on to a new line where it is discarded leaving a completely empty last line of the paragraph which generates the warning.

Comment: Thank you so much :)